# React-Native + Mobx + React Navigation : Error: MobX injector: Store '...' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, mobx

I can't resolve this issue from my code.. When I switch to filmdetail view I got this error :  Error: MobX injector: Store '...' is not available! Make sure it is provided by some Provider

Here my app.js
APP.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from "react-native";

import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation';
import FilmStore from './Stores/FilmStore';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{FilmStore.test}</Text>
                <Navigation filmStore={FilmStore} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Here the navigation from React Navigation
Navigation.JS

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

// Views
import Search from '../Components/Search'
import FilmDetail from "../Components/FilmDetail";

const SearchStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Search: {
        screen: Search,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Rechercher'
        }
    },
    FilmDetail: {
        screen: FilmDetail,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Détail'
        }
    },
});

export default SearchStackNavigator;
```

Here the film detail view 
FilmDetail.JS

```
import React from 'react'
import Moment from 'moment';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';

import {StyleSheet, View, Text, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView, Image, Button} from 'react-native'
import {getDetail, getImageURI} from "../API/TMDBApi";

@inject('filmStore')

@observer
class FilmDetail extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default FilmDetail
```

Looking for help :)
Thanks !

Comment: try import observer and inject from `mobx-react/native`

Comment: Same error with mobx-react/native

Answer (score 0):

I replaced in app.js

```
..
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
..

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{FilmStore.test}</Text>
            <Navigation filmStore={FilmStore} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

by

```
..
import { observer, Provider } from 'mobx-react';
..

render() {
    return (
        <Provider filmStore={filmStore}>
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <Text>{filmStore.test}</Text>
                <Navigation />
            </View>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

Now it works perfectly.